# Why do academic papers often gloss over effect sizes?

Tags: effect-size, publication-bias, academia

This may be just my perception, but it seems like academic papers often focus on whether or not they found a statistically significant correlation between two variables and spend very little time discussing the effect size to put the finding in a larger context.

For example if there was a paper about whether eating almonds is good for your heart, the paper might say, "we found a significant correlation between eating almonds and reduced mortality from heart-related issues"
But little or no discussion as to how the effect size stacks up to other variables. For example I could imagine the effect size of eating almonds could be 1/100th the effect size of losing 10kg even though the difference is statistically significant.

Is this simply a case of trying to make your study more interesting so it gets published, or are there valid reasons for shying away from talking about effect sizes?

For example: With a linear regression, you may be 99.98% sure that the there is SOME correlation between two variables, but your confidence in the effect size could be much lower.

I could imagine saying something like "we are 99.98% confidence that the effect size is between 1.1 and 0.3 standard deviations, but I have never seen something like that in practice.

Comment: Can you post some papers where the authors report significance without effect size? Also, which field of science are you referring to? In my experience (biology), a decent paper does report effect size with some measure of uncertainty (stderr, confidence interavals, ...) and some plots showing the spread of the data. Then whether and to what extent there is some bias in the estimation of effect size is another matter.